# How to run/start VsCode on Centos 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos

I'm a beginner studying centos.
I installed centos and vscode, but there's no response when I click the vscode icon.
And when i enter the [code] at the terminal, only an error message comes out and it can't be executed (the screen below).

​And if you look at the top left of my screen, it says [Activities]. Is this normal?
I saw [Applications] other centos image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ6MB.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6AQa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Both problems stem from logging in as the `root` user. This is not a good idea for many reasons (e.g., security, desktop shortcuts do not work correctly, etc.), and, once deployed, your program may not work correctly for non-privileged users.

If you need to run as `root`, the command from the Terminal is:

`code "/home/<your default username>/<optional projects directory>" --user-data-dir="." --no-sandbox`

**Output:**

[image: VS Code Welcome as Root]

However, if you have no reason to use `root` over `sudo`, I strongly recommend you log out as `root`, and run VS Code as a regular user. Also, VS Code will continue to warn you about being `root`.

As far as the Gnome desktop, **Applications** on CentOS 7 and **Activities** on CentOS 8+.